# may i know what is wrong in this circuit?.. forward-reverse motor

Tags: motor

[image: forward-reverse motor]
what is wrong in this circuit

this is a circuit for a forward-reverse motor.. what is wrong on this??
I made it on PCB board and it doesn't work!!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is exceptionally unhelpful when it comes to debugging. What happens? What have you tried, and what measurements did you take to debug it?

Comment: first i made it on test board and it works.. then when i tried it on PCB it doesn't.. there is no volt out to the motor

Comment: Start with simple troubleshooting: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/226  then double check that the PCB really represents the schematic. We can't tell from just the schematic what might have been done wrong in making the PCB or what might have been done wrong in populating the board.

Comment: While you are at it, check that your schematic also matches what you built on your test board.

Comment: Where di you get the circuit? Did you used IDENTICAL MOSFETS in the breadboard version? Is the power on the gates? Where is it supplied from? (12V, div, ...?) | Your drive voltages are VERY suspect as Andy says. It should not have ever worked IF you used the same MOSFETs. Top FETs need at least +10V on gates to turn off safely AND you have Vdiv = 9V supply on LM324 and LM324 Vout max is < Vdd by say 1.5V so max gate V on PFETs is maybe 7.5V so top FETS are always on. || You should label your diagrams with full part numbers and provide links to data sheets. People should not have to peer ...|

Comment: ... text in SMALL letters by the gates and wonder what 4031 means when it is really [**CD4081 AND gate - datasheet here**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4073b.pdf)

Comment: Overall the cct looks OKish except for the voltage levels being fatally bad. Please answer various questions asked if you want moe input.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You can't depend on the datasheet numbers with this circuit- the datasheet is written assuming a load to ground- the 10K pullups should make the static voltage levels okay provided they don't have to source any current. It will be **very** slow to switch and probably have shoot-through current.

Comment: @Spehro I'd be doubtful. If the 324 was operated from the +12V supply then the 10k just has to pull the gate to less that Vgsth from rail and in fact the 324 would get there by itself.
However, the 324 has "div" as Vdd and this is about +9V if I understand the purpose of his 470/1k/470 divider correctly. I closed the MOSFET datasheet, but first plotted line was Vgs = 4.5V and typical curve had it turning on in the Vgs = 2 to 3V region. To be safe you;d want Vgs < 2V say so > +10V. With the 324's Vdd = 9V you need to pull the output to 1V above Vdd. If it managed 0.6V above Vdd you MAY survive.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Ah, I did not see that and assumed it was operated from the 12V (can't read it on this screen), which appears to be an error. Why in the world would he want to do that! The pullup may in fact work at pulling it up to the +12, even with the lower supply (there are no protection diodes in an LM324- just parasitic diodes to GND). I just don't know about that one.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to read the supply voltage on the LM324 but, assuming it is 12 volts i.e. common to the voltage rail on the H bridge, you'll never properly turn-off the top MOSFETs because, the LM324's output can not swing higher than about 10V (on a 12 volt supply). Other than that, there does not appear to be a logic supply on the AND gates.

Comment: neg and div are generated at lhs of cct. div is 9v and use for 324 supply. Neg is 3v and is used as a reference for PWM and direction to be compared with by input 324s used as comparators. Top FETs are enabled when direction control on their side is low. When direction control on other side goes high pwm is applied to lower FET on other side. Lower FETsa are gate driven - IF they have 12V PSU then may work. [IRF9540N](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf9540nspbf.pdf) has ~=3V Vgsth so top FET should always be on as you suggest due to both 324 max swing AND low Vdd on 324.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect visually, check the supplies, check the voltages at the MOSFET gates (with the 10K pull-ups I think they should be okay). Check the input voltages at each op-amp pin including power.

The schematic looks okay to me, except those diodes appear incorrect. They should presumably parallel the MOSFETs. This kind of error will generally not be picked up by DRC because the pins go somewhere. That may not be what's causing whatever problem you're seeing though.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "no volt out on the motor" do you mean that the LEDs don't light? Or do you have a meter which is telling you no voltage across the motor? If the latter, you need to measure each motor lead with respect to ground, and see what that tells you. If the former, you desperately need to buy a cheap DMM and learn to use it.

To begin with, over on the left you use R6/R4/R5 to generate 2 voltages. One of them, "neg" is about 3 volts, and you clearly use it as logic reference level. The other, which seems to be "dlv" or something (I can't read it clearly) is used as the supply voltage to your LM324. I assume that it's also intended to be the supply voltage for your CD4081, but no connection is shown. Factoring the load effect of the LM324, dlv will be at about 8 volts, although R2 and R3 may possibly act as effective pullups. As a result, since the LM324 will not drive closer than a couple of volts to its positive supply, The gate voltages of Q1 and Q2 will never get higher than 6-7 volts, and Q1 and Q2 will always be on. If R2 and R3 are indeed pulling up the gates, you are overdriving the 4081 inputs by several volts, and there is no telling what they are putting out.

If you change R5 to 330 ohms and short R6, and also connect the 4081 to dlv, the circuit might possibly work for DC levels on your PWM input. Then again, it might not. It would depend on just how strong the 324s are feeling, and on exactly what the gate threshold voltage of Q1 and Q2 are. If the 324 is weak, and Vgsth is at the low end, Q1 and Q2 may not fully turn off, and either your 12 volt supply will current limit or the FETs will get hot.

If you expect to PWM your motor to control speed, you're probably out of luck. Neither the 324 nor the 4081 have enough current output to drive the gate capacitances at any speed. Plus, your spike protection diodes (D1 - D4) do not appear to actually be connected to your motor leads.

Finally, I notice that you have 2 sections of the 4081 unused, with one section completely unaccounted for. Both sections should have their inputs grounded. With CMOS, all inputs must be connected to one level or another, and leaving unused inputs to float (even for unused gates) can have bizarre consequences. It's unlikely that this is your problem, given the other issues, but you need to do it anyways.